# Filter Dart stream to allow only one event per second

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

Given a dart stream, how can I filter it so that there is maximum one value per minute?

Somthing like:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Filtering-Observables#throttlefirst

**Background**
I'm building a flutter app.
I use getPositionStream to get a stream of the location.
When I recieve a positionChange I update a GoogleMap.
However getPositionStream returns too many events, so I want to filter them to speed up the response.

### EDIT

Note for @pskink comment
This should be emmiting max one location change each second?

```
getPositionStream(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best).throttleTime(Duration(seconds: 1))
```

Comment: could i see your code ? to see what kind of stream controller you use

Comment: i missed you are using `rxdart`, so what is wrong with: https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/ThrottleExtensions/throttleTime.html ?

Comment: @pskink This may be what I was looking for, but can't make it work. Can you check my edited question? Thanks!

Comment: yes, it looks fine, what does not work with it?

Comment: Ok, yes its working, the view was rebuilding too much, but the cause was not the Stream. Working great, thanks!

Comment: sure, your welcome